# Two different mappings to ONE XML output file

Tags: talend

I'm working on a talend job where I have a excel file and a couple of database fields that gets mapped to an XML file.

The working job looks like this:

[image]

Problem: I want to, with the same input of the excel file and the database fields, make another mapping that outputs to the same working XML file mentioned ealier. So I will have ONE XML file with TWO different mappings. How can I achieve this?

**Update**
I have done this mapping: [image]

which in the end gets exported like this:
[image]

but I'm unsure on how to use this mapping in the tAdvancedFileOutputXML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to have a single XML file containing two different XMLs (the second one appended to the first one). In the shown Job add a OnSubJobOk link to point to a duplicate of your document flow which has a different mapping. In the second flow rather than using tFileOutputXML component to write the XML file, you can use the tAdvancedFileOutputXML with Append Source XML File marked to add to the file generated from the first flow. Also make sure to configure the XML tree. Check the following link for further information https://help.talend.com/reader/~hSvVkqNtFWjDbBHy0iO_w/h3wZegFH1_1XfusiUGtsPg

[image: tAdvancedFileOutputXML]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get the following error "parameter root must have at least one value" on the tAdvancedFileOutputXML component. Do you know why?

Comment: Have you defined the Configure XML Tree, you need to at least have a root node there. You should build the new XML structure there.

Comment: Thanks got it, but how can I use the second tXMLMap I have done in the XML tree, because my export type is "Document"?

Comment: If I got your question correctly, in the second tXMLMap build your new XML structure. Then just map every field coming from the tXMLMap to the tags inside the tAdvancedFileOutputXML XML tree.

Comment: I have updating my question.

Comment: The values in the expression of tAdvancedFileOutputXML are wrong, it cannot be static. There should be the fields coming from the tXMLMap through the row. Once you obtain the fields there you can drag and drop the value of every field to every tag of the tree. Check the link that I have sent before for reference.